# Change The Background Color Of A Button On The Fly Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a style

```
.someRedStuff
{
 background:red !important;
}
```

I want to change the color of the star icon to red when the button is clicked

```
 <a data-role="button" data-iconpos= "notext" data-icon="star" id="custom-li-3" onclick="changeColor()"></a>
```

I tried this code but it does not seem to be doing the trick..

```
  function changeColor()
        {          
            $('#custom - li - 3').removeClass('ui-icon-star').addClass('someRedStuff');
        }
```

How do I change the color of the star icon on click?

Comment: jQuery Mobile is most probably modifying the tags (adding additional HTML) when it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element selector has spaces it.
Removes the spaces in the selector to match the id declared for the element.

```
$('#custom-li-3').removeClass('ui-icon-star').addClass('someRedStuff');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3cA8K/

JS

```
$('#custom-li-3').on('click', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('someRedStuff');
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">

   <div data-role="content">
      <a data-role="button" data-iconpos= "notext" data-icon="star" id="custom-li-3"></a>
   </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.someRedStuff
{
 background:red !important;
}
```